# Iptables rules which only whitelist dns and drop everything else

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables

I'm trying to configure iptables with `DROP` as default policy for `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` on a dns server, but something is going wrong.

Here is my iptables script

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP 
iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

There's been some packet loss, because computers that depend on this service dns only navigate when iptables is cleaned.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: So you only want DNStraffic to come in and go out? Nothing else? Not even SSH? Not HTTP? Nothing at all? Do you have local physical access to this server?

Comment: What is the exact purpose for this server?

Comment: @Wesley Yes, just dns entry and exit and ssh.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Resolve queries dns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your policy is "Only allow inbound DNS queries to the server and DNS answers from the server for IPv4", your ruleset looks fine. But this is probably not what you want. For example, the policy implies that your DNS server has a magic local database which it can use to answer all DNS queries.

Some educated guesses what might cause the problems:

- Does your DNS server need to perform recursive DNS queries when it tries to answer one of your client's queries? If so, you should allow this (outgoing DNS queries from your DNS server).
- Are some of your clients using IPv6 to query DNS. I assume your server is not firewalled for IPv6?
- Are some of your client's IPv4 queries working because the server recursively does a query with IPv6?
- Do you have more interfaces than `eth0` and `lo`?
- Are there some ICMP error messages which your server is not sending/receiving because your iptables blocks it? If for some reason some clients might require IPv4 fragmentation or there are MTU issues, your clients cannot resolve this because your server does not tell them via ICMP.

Also: You might want to allow your server to get system updates. In addition, you want your server to be able to respond to certain ICMP requests and you definitely need that your server is able to handle ICMP for IPv6.

edit: Try this (you might probably want to fine-tune icmp handling):

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Comment: The server works only with an interface and all the jobs are done with IPv4, the server works with recursive dns. How do you allow this type of operation? and how do I handle IPv4 ICMP packets?

Comment: I edited my answer and added an `iptables-save` script for you (ready to be copy&pasted).